# Not able to print data from Html in Php file

Tags: php, html

```
<body>
<span>
<div class="heading">
  <h3><img src="http://zicom.com/img/ilayashop-1482233381.jpg" alt="Zicom   Logo" ></h3> 
  <h1><i>Zicom </i> SMS Application</h1><br>

</span>
</div>

 <br>
  <div>
<form method='post' action=''>
  <label for="fname">Contact Number</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="number" placeholder="Contact Number....">



   <label for="sms" id="msg">Message</label>
  <select id="country" name="message">
  <option value="" name="message">Blank</option>
  <option value="hello" name="message">Abandoned Call</option>
  <option value="" name="message">Audit Call </option>
 </select>
 <input type="text"id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Type your Message...." >



 <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
 </form>
</div>
<?php

 if(isset($_POST)) {

 $n = $_POST['number'];
  $m = $_POST['message'];
  echo "$n $m";
  }
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have used the same method many times and i have succesfully sent the data to php file, but im unable to do the same. I try to print the content of form, but is not executing.

Comment: You don't need to use `name="message"` in your `select`'s options

Comment: I'm voting this as a typographical error.

Comment: You can not use the same `name` attribute twice in one form, like you do it with `<select name="message" ...>` and `<input name="message" ...>`

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` outside the if statement to see if any data is being sent